# Wait for async function with callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

I have an async method from a package module with a callback function. The method itself returns undefined.

I've very new to async coding and would like to be able to halt the execution of the program until a variable arrayWithData is assigned data from the callback method.

e.g.

```
let dataFiles = fs.etc   

function makeDataArray(dataFiles) {
   let arrayWithData = [];
   for (let dataFile in dataFiles) {
     package.magicMethodToParseData(dataFile, function(result){ //async method with callback
        arrayWithData.push(result) //happens later
     });
   }
   return arrayWithData; //This returns undefined
}

function doSomethingWithData(dataArray) {
   /* Doing Stuff with Data Array */
}

/* Broken Code with undefined */
doSomethingWithData( makeDataArray(dataFiles) );
```

I know I can just add the rest of my execution inside the callback function but want to avoid that and keep the code flat.

### How can I wait for data to be assigned to the array and then continue execution?

Update: Added github tester project to showcase the full problem as the promise keeps getting rejected..
Github Link: https://github.com/Jonathan002/autofont.git

Comment: The array will contain multiple values. I updated the example to be more clear.

Comment: Thank you, and is `dataFiles` an array? Perhaps you meant to use `for of` instead of `for in` (`for in` is for iterating the keys of objects).

Comment: Take a look at this link for some interesting insight on the effect of loops on async javascript https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a `Promise` which contains the array using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). The parameter to `Promise.all` must be an array of promises, and it returns a promise of an array of values.

You can use it like this:

```
function makeDataArray(dataFiles) {
  return Promise.all(dataFiles.map(function (dataFile) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      package.magicMethodToParseData(dataFile, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      });
    });
  }));
}

makeDataArray(dataFiles)
  .then(doSomethingWithData)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Hi 4castle, I've been trying to use your implementation of promises but have not been able to get the **then** statement to execute. I'm trying to make it work with this package and it's callback: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontmachine

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer so that it uses the error present in the callback of that API. If you need, you could also update your question with your actual code instead of the example code.

Comment: Thanks 4castle for the update and sorry I couldn't respond yesterday. I've been trying to work on the promise with the resolve nested inside the callback function like you have suggested but the promise keeps on getting rejected. I have produced a github tester project to showcase the exact scenario: [github Link](https://github.com/Jonathan002/autofont.git).

Comment: I'm having some trouble getting `fontmachine` to install, but what is the error that it reports when the promise rejects?

Comment: I updated the github project to include the node_modules if your having trouble getting fontmachine. As for the error it uses the callback error from fontmachine **Error: could not open font file** on reject. However the callback **will** eventually retrieve the font files and I have logged the list. Once the font files are retrieved the if else statement has already executed and I'm having trouble halting the if-else to wait for it.

Comment: Hi 4castle have finally solved it! The if (error) statement always ran because it is truthy from the start just rejecting the promise right away.  Had tried it with resolve() alone and was able to get the data I needed. Thanks for your help. : )

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jonathan this is a very common scenario with async programming. You can use native promises with es6 or us a promise library such as bluebird or q.
Here is a code example

```
   function someAsyncFunction() {
       // return promise here 
   }

  const promiseArray = [];

  // some random loop 
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  promiseArray.push(someAsyncFunction());

}
 Promise.all(promiseArray).then((results)=> {
 // resolved promises
console.log(results);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('errors ', errors);
})
```

If you need a good understanding of how promises work you can read the Promise documentation on MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise